# Continuity of Integral.

Tags: real-analysis

> If $f $ is a nonnegative measurable function, then prove that for $E_n = \{x : f(x) \leq n, |x| \leq n \}$, we get
>
> $$\lim_{n \to \infty } \int_{A_n} f = \int f dm$$

I said something along the lines of $f_n \leq f_{n +1}$, with $f_n = f\mathbb{1}_{|x| \leq n \cap f \leq n}$ and it converges point wise. Then apply Monotone Convergence Theoerem or something along those lines, but this requires the two sets $\{f(x) \leq n\}$ and $\{|x| \leq n\}$ to be disjoint.

Comment: Why do they need to be disjoint? If you increase $n$ both sets increase and their intersection also increases.

Comment: If those two sets were disjoint, then $f_n = 0$ everywhere. That is just the opposite of what is required!